# Wash Sale information

Tags: wash-sale

I sold 100 shares at loss. Can I sell the put option NOW, which gets exercised **after** 31 days; is it considered a wash sale?

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag. You might also want to provide more details about the trades; you mentioned shares, but also a put option. What was the overall trading strategy?

Comment: From what I recall, selling the put, regardless of expiration can't happen within 30 days of the stock sale for loss unless the put is unlikely to be exercised (which is not well-defined). So the guidance I've read is to sell slightly OTM in these cases. Hopefully someone can answer with some proper citations.

Comment: When it comes to options, IRS rules are not clear as to what constitutes a wash sale.  Here's the opinion of a reputable tax organization: [Tax Treatment For Trading Options](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-options/)